# why is this C++/CLI code not adding the files to a listbox

Tags: winforms, file, listbox, c++-cli

I have this c++ code that is supposed to detect when a file has been modified in a directory and add the file name to a list box.

This is the file watcher part which is inside a button that starts the monitoring process

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    array<String^>^ args = Environment::GetCommandLineArgs();

    FileSystemWatcher^ fsWatcher = gcnew FileSystemWatcher( );
    fsWatcher->Path = "C:\\users\\patchvista2";
    fsWatcher->IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    fsWatcher->NotifyFilter = static_cast<NotifyFilters> 
              (NotifyFilters::FileName | 
               NotifyFilters::Attributes | 
               NotifyFilters::LastAccess | 
               NotifyFilters::LastWrite | 
               NotifyFilters::Security | 
               NotifyFilters::Size );

    Form1^ handler = gcnew Form1(); 
    fsWatcher->Changed += gcnew FileSystemEventHandler(handler, &Form1::OnChanged);
    fsWatcher->Created += gcnew FileSystemEventHandler(handler, &Form1::OnChanged);

    fsWatcher->EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

then for the onchange part I have this code

```
void OnChanged (Object^ source, FileSystemEventArgs^ e)
{
    // Here is the problem
    MessageBox::Show(e->FullPath);
    listBox1->Items->Add(e->FullPath);
    // End problem

    System::Security::Cryptography::MD5 ^ md5offile = MD5CryptoServiceProvider::Create();
    array<Byte>^ hashValue;
    FileStream^ fs = File::Open(e->FullPath, IO::FileMode::Open, IO::FileAccess::Read, IO::FileShare::ReadWrite);
    fs->Position = 0;
    hashValue = md5offile->ComputeHash(fs);
    PrintByteArray(hashValue);
    fs->Close();
    Application::DoEvents();
}
```

It will message box me the file name but it will not add it to the list box. I tried having it display the file name to a label but that did not work either. it seems like the screen is not refreshing once this code loop is started. I have this code in vb.net and it does add the file name to the list box. can someone show me why the file name is not getting added tot the list box.

Comment: Just to be clear: this is not C++ code; a properly functioning C++ compiler must reject it for basic syntax errors (e.g., `Object^ source`).

Comment: You need to invalidate the listbox after you update it. I'm not familiar with managed C++ so I don't know how you'd go about that. You also need to be running the message loop.

Comment: @JerryCoffin it's C++/CLI I have corrected the question title.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You need to keep the FileSystemWatcher alive. It's liable to be garbage collected where you've got it now. (Create a class field and stick it there.)
2. You need to [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) onto the UI thread whenever you do anything with a UI component.

Here's the approximate syntax for #2 (I'm away from a compiler at the moment, this may not be exact.)

```
void Form1::AddToListBox(String^ filename)
{
    listBox1->Items->Add(filename);
}

void Form1::OnChanged(Object^ source, FileSystemEventArgs^ e)
{
    Action<String^>^ addDelegate = gcnew Action<String^>(this, &Form1::AddToListBox);
    this->Invoke(addDelegate, e->FullPath);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Really? Why? C# doesn't require this.. isn't the event raised on the UI thread?

Comment: All WinForms components, whether C#, VB, or C++/CLI require making changes only on the UI thread. I just double checked the documentation for the FileSystemWatcher, I didn't see anything in there about it raising events on the UI thread, so I'd expect that the Invoke would be required in C# as well.

Comment: Fascinating.. I'll have to go back and look at my old FSW projects.. I don't remember doing this :/

Comment: so I added the new void Form1::AddToListBox(String^ filename) and this was fine but I added Action<String^>^ addDelegate = gcnew Action<String^>^(this, &Form1::AddToListBox);
    this->Invoke(addDelegate, e->FullPath); to the top of my onchange code and i got error C3698: 'System::Action<T> ^' : cannot use this type as argument of 'gcnew' so what am I suppose to do

Comment: the compiler also says with
          [
              T=System::String ^
          ] 
          did you mean 'System::Action<T>' (without the top-level '^')?
          with
          [
              T=System::String ^
          ] so what is it telling me to fix

Comment: okay I got it to compile right change this part "gcnew Action<String^>^" to this "gcnew Action<String^>" but it still does not add the file name to the list box so what am I doing wrong